# Adding element to next free space in array

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I have an array

```
String[] path={abc,bcd};
```

I pass this array in a method:

```
addElement(path);
```

In method

```
void addElement(String[] path)
{
    // here i got value suppose "qsd" and i want to add it after "bcd" ie 2 index of array
    path[path.lenght]="qsd"; 
}
```

But this is giving me an error.

I dont want to use an ArrayList.

Comment: @Adrian
not home work. learning GWT.Learnt many things. Still my base of java is not that strong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is that arrays in Java are not trivially resizable. What you wind up doing instead is actually creating a new array, and adding each of the elements to that. This will be slower than the `ArrayList` code, and uglier as well.

This also means that any code which points to the old array will no longer work. If you only have one instance, you could have `addElement` return the new array like so

```
String[] addElement(String old[]){
    String arr[] = new String[old.length+1];
    //copy all the elements in old...
    arr[old.length] = "whatever";
    return arr;
}
```

Then use

```
path = addElement(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ArrayList`

Otherwise you have to resize the array by allocating new memory of the size of the original array +1, copy the elements from the old one to the new one, and add in the new element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size  of emulated array in GWT (even if javascript arrays support this stuff). You'll have always  to create a new instance of array. Most common way to solve this problem is to use one of the collection classes (like `java.util.ArrayList`) . Example:

```
ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc","bbc"));
path.add("qsd");
```